# Phantom existential types in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write a value class that wraps Scala collection's `Map` and provides an alternative `get`. I'm trying to use a phantom type in the value class and tag the `Key` with the same type using the method `member`. If the result of `member` is `Some(k)` then the user should be able to call `get(k)` and get a `V` instead of an `Option[V]`.

```scala
import scala.collection.{Map => M}

class Key[PH, K] private (val k: K) extends AnyVal

object Key {
  def apply[PH, K](k: K): Key[PH, K] = new Key(k)
}

class Map[PH, K, V] private (val m: M[K, V]) extends AnyVal {
  def member(k: K): Option[Key[PH, K]] = m.get(k).map(_ => Key(k))

  def get(key: Key[PH, K]): V = m.get(key.k).get
}

object Map {
  def apply[PH, K, V](m: M[K, V]): Map[PH, K, V] = new Map(m)
}

def withMap[K, V, T](m: M[K, V])(cont: (Map[PH, K, V] forSome { type PH }) => T): T = cont(Map(m))

withMap(M("a" -> "a")){ m =>
  m.member("a") match {
    case Some(v) => println(m.get(v))
    case None => println(":(")
  }
}
```

But currently it fails compiling with the following error:

```
found   : Key[PH(in value $anonfun),String] where type +PH(in value $anonfun)
required: Key[PH(in value cont),String]
    case Some(v) => println(m.get(v))
```

How can I convince scalac that the `PH`s are the same?

Comment: I think you have to restrict this to immutable maps, because a mutable map can have a key taken out of it after you've already given out a `Key` for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destructure the existential:

```
withMap(M("a" -> "a")) { case m =>
  m.member("a") match {
    case Some(v) => println(m.get(v))
    case None => println(":(")
  }
}
```

This abbreviates

```
withMap(M("a" -> "a")) { case m: Map[ph, String, String] => // name the phantom type ph, name the map m =>
  m.member("a") match {
    case Some(v) => println(m.get(v))
    case None => println(":(")
  }
}
```

The destructuring allows `m` to be given a non-existential type in terms of a newly introduced type variable. This means that every occurrence of `m` can now have the same type.

Comment: Thanks. This indeed fixes the problem but admittedly leaves a lot to be desired, ergonomic wise. It probably constitutes a separate question but can you think of another encoding that would alleviate destructuring? Ideally the consumer of `withMap` shouldn't know about the phantom type.

Answer (score 1):

Phantom types are meaningless. You should say what you mean: every `Key` belongs to a certain `Map`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.Map // it is not safe to use Maps in general!

class KeyedMap[K, V](val m: Map[K, V]) extends AnyVal {
  import KeyedMap._
  def member(k: K): Option[Key[K, V, m.type]] = m.get(k).map { _ => new Key[K, V, m.type](k) }
  def fromKey(k: Key[K, V, m.type]): V = m(k.k)
}
object KeyedMap {
  //                              vvvvvvvvvvvvvv requires this parameter to be <something>.type
  class Key[K, +V, M <: Map[K, V] with Singleton] private[KeyedMap](val k: K) extends AnyVal
}

object Test {
  def main(args: String*): Unit = {
    val m = new KeyedMap(Map("a" -> "b"))
    m.member("a") match {
      case Some(v) => println(m.fromKey(v))
      case None => println(":(")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really helpful. However, this would tie the `Key` to `Map`. Ideally `Key` will be a separate entity and possibly reusable across few more datatypes of `scala.collection.immutable`.